# Loading indicator for HTML5 Audio tag / mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediaelement.js

Is there a way for javascript/jQuery to know if the source file for an `<audio>` tag has been/is being loaded?

I am using mediaelement.js, however I'll accept an answer that works for just a regular `<audio>` tag. Currently I'm faking the loading indication:

```
$("#temp-loading").spin(minySpinner);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#temp-loading').spin(false);
}, 12000);
```

(`spin()` is a function from [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/)). Obviously the indicator is meaningless in this case, but people were getting confused when the page was loaded but the audio was taking about 15 seconds to start playing, so I had to implement this temporary solution. I'd like it to actually indicate if the file is still being loaded, though, so on slower connections the icon will remain until the file has actually started playing.

Also of note is that I have the element set to `autoplay` (it's okay, I promise!), so when the page is loaded it automatically starts "playing", even though no actual audio is happening yet. This makes it hard to use the `play` event to stop the spinner, since it just stops immediately. So I'll either have to stop the spinner when the audio actually starts, or not PLAY until the audio is actually ready to be played, if that makes sense.

I also noticed that while the audio file is loading, the time indicator says, "00:00". When it's loaded, it changes to "00:00:00". So it seems that the ability to do what I need is already built-in, I just need to know how to use it.

If it makes a difference, the file is a live stream (via Icecast). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the `canplay` event?

**EDIT** 
Since I got the points, I'd better paste brick's solution for posterity:

```
$("audio").mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 150,
    features: ['playpause','current','volume'],
    success: function(element) { 
        element.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){
            $("#temp-loading").spin(false);
        }, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Has the same results as the loadeddata. Works in Webkit, but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I've half-way solved it with the following:

```
$("#temp-loading").spin(minnerSpinner);
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){
    $("#temp-loading").spin(false);
});
```

However this is not a cross-browser solution (works in Chrome and Safari, not Firefox).

**edit** I have it working with jQuery now, but still doesn't work for Firefox (which is using mediaelement's Flash fallback). At this point it's not an html5 question anymore, it's a mediaelement problem.

```
$('audio').bind('loadeddata', function(){
    $("#temp-loading").spin(false);
});
```

**edit 2** I ended up getting it work following Tetaxa's suggestion... not exactly what he/she suggested, but it gave me the idea to use the `success` callback:

```
$("audio").mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 150,
    features: ['playpause','current','volume'],
    success: function(element) { 
        element.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){
            $("#temp-loading").spin(false);
        }, false);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `audio.addEventListener('MozAudioAvailable', audioAvailableFunction, false);` in Firefox?

Comment: @Tetaxa yes, but it doesn't change anything. The spinner continues to spin.

Comment: Can you bind the `loadeddata` event to mediaelement instead of the audio element with the `new MediaElement(opts)` constructor?

Comment: Your suggestion gave me the idea to use the `success` callback, and it works now. See my updated answer. Thank you! If you post an answer I will accept it.